# Show that if n is odd, then the equation $x^2-y^2=2n$ has no integer solutions x,y.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The question also says to consider modulo 4 of the equation which I have no idea how to apply.

Comment: $x^2\equiv0,1\pmod4$. So, $4\mid x^2-y^2$, or $2\not\mid x^2-y^2$.

Comment: How did you get the congruency of x^2 to be 0 and 1?

Comment: @abdin try $x$ even and odd, and see what that implies modulo 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=2k+1$ is odd, then $2n = 4k+2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

The squares mod $4$ are $0^2 = 2^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and $1^2 = 3^2 \equiv 1\pmod 4$.

It follows that $x^2-y^2\pmod 4$ can be either $0$, $1$, or $-1\equiv 3$, but not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The only squares mod 4 are zero and one (because $0^2\equiv_4 0$, $1^2\equiv_4 1$, $2^2\equiv_4 0$ and $3^2\equiv_4 1$). This means that whatever value you substitute for $x$ and $y$, the left-hand side of your equation will always give you zero, one or three. However, because $n$ is odd, $2n$ reduces to 2 mod 4. This gives a contradiction, because on the left-hand side you have 0, 1 or 3 and on the right-hand side you get 2.

Answer (score 0):

As $x+y+(x-y)$ is even,

$x+y,x-y$ have the same parity

If both are odd, so will be $x^2-y^2$

Else $(x+y)(x-y)$ will be divisible by $2^2$